# unregister scroll for canvas

Tags: html, canvas, kineticjs

i have a page with kineticjs that creates a canvas in size of 480*960
the problem is when i view it on my phone i can't scroll lower than the canvas.

how do i unregister the touch events to the stage?

my code is similar to this:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="other">other stuff</div>
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 480,
    height: 960
  });
  var uploaded;
  var mask;
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
  var imageObj = new Image();
  var maskObj = new Image();
  mask = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 130,
      y: 50,
      image: maskObj,
      width: newwidth,
      height: newheight
    });
  uploaded = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 105,
      y: 130,
      image: imageObj,
      width: 160,
      height: 240,
      offset: [95,120],
      draggable: true
    });
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    layer.add(mask);
    layer.add(uploaded);
    stage.add(layer);
    uploaded.on('mouseout', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
      });
    uploaded.on('mouseover', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      });
    mask.on('mouseover', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
      });

  };
imageObj.src = 'pic1.png';
maskObj.src = 'pic2.png';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so in the end i solved it with a simple scroll that triggered by touchmove

```
uploaded.on('touchmove',function(e) {
        //still need an action here that would stop scrolling meanwhile the photo is dragged.
      },uploaded.off('touchmove'),mask.on('touchmove',function(e) {
          var currentY = e.touches[0].clientY;
          var currentX = e.touches[0].clientX;
          if(currentY > lastY){
            window.scrollTo(currentX,$(document).scrollTop()-15);
          }else{
            window.scrollTo(currentX,$(document).scrollTop()+15);
          }
             lastY = currentY;
        }));
```